# Function returning sum of all values not what is being sent in as parameter

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a total for all the records in a group but cant seem to get it to use the parameter sent in.

Here is the function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION f_medicare_claim_totals(bat_invoice VARCHAR(45)) 
    RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2) 
    READS SQL DATA 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE f_medicare_total DECIMAL(10,2); 
    SELECT sum(medicare_allowable_total)
    INTO f_medicare_total 
    FROM v_materialized_view_pa 
    WHERE bat_invoice=bat_invoice; 

    RETURN(f_medicare_total);  
END;
```

If I select the function with a value of `7944` like this:

```
SELECT f_medicare_claim_totals(7944) as total
```

The value returned to the query is the value of the entire column.
like it was doing the query without the where command.

I know I am knew to this, but hopefully someone can see where my issue is..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your parameter name being the same as a column name. The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html) discourage this:

> > A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a SELECT ... INTO statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable.

According to this, your `WHERE` clause is basically saying `WHERE 7944 = 7944`.

Try changing your parameter name and see if that helps.

Comment: bingo that worked...  but wow this made the query hang.. only doing a little over 4500 rows and it taking over 5 minutes to return the results... any ideas why?

Comment: Ah yes - it made my "glad to hear it" look pretty cold-hearted :) I'll remove that comment in a minute. As for why it's hanging, it depends on the how `v_materialized_view_pa` is set up. If it's a table you can try an index on the `bat_invoice` column. If it's a view, then from what I see MySQL doesn't give you much help with optimization. But I'm not an expert on MySQL views, so if this is a view I'd suggest looking into what can be done to optimize a MySQL view. Sorry I can't be of more help than that.